# Why refresh token is coming undefined from firebase if I open my website after a long time.?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I have created my website using react and used firebase for authentication .Whenever the token is expired I fetch new access token from firebase using refresh token. But if I open my website after a long time then refresh token is coming undefined due to which I am unable to fetch new access token and call the APIs.Because of this user need to logout and login again.

I checked with the firebase documentation as well

[https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#:~:text=Firebase%20ID%20tokens%20are%20short,The%20user%20is%20disabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#:%7E:text=Firebase%20ID%20tokens%20are%20short,The%20user%20is%20disabled)

but nothing of the mentioned reason has happened

Comment: Did you change the default [Authentication State Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec no